# Sqoop and Multiline free form query

Tags: sql, oracle, sqoop

I'm trying to sqoop some data using a free form query, it's only that my queries are pretty long (several JOINs and PIVOT for several columns) and it's really messy to include within the Sqoop command itself. I know that I can create a .props file and put my query there. My `file.props` is of the form:

```
import
--connect
jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:sid
--username
user
--password
password1
--query
'SELECT col1, col2, ..., col18,"'pivotedcol1'", ..., "'pivotedcol21'"\
FROM (SELECT col1, ..., col18, DEFINITIONS,\
      to_char(to_date(TIME),'DD.MM.YY', 'YYYY-MM-DD')   \      
       FROM    table1\
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2\
       ON      table2.colX = table1.colX\
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table3\
       ON      table2.colY = table3.colX\
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table4\
       ON      table4.colX = table1.colX\
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table5\
       ON      table5.colX = table4.colY\
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table6\
       ON      table5.colY = table6.colX\
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table7\
       ON      table7.colX = table1.colX\
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table8\
       ON      table7.colY = table8.colX\
     WHERE ROWNUM <= 45000 AND $CONDITIONS)\
PIVOT (MAX(TIME) FOR DEFINITIONS IN ('pivotedcol1', ..., 'pivotedcol21'))'
--as-avrodatafile
--verbose
--target-dir
directory/freeform
```

After running

```
sqoop --options-file file.props
```

I get an error

```
ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Error while expanding arguments java.lang.Exception: Multiline quoted strings not supported in file(file.props)
```

Where's mistake? Can I be doing something better?

Comment: Maybe the answer is in the errormessage: Multiline strings is not supported. So put your query on a single line, maybe that works?

Comment: It felt kind of silly, but I did just that. Got the error `ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character` No idea where it actually broke, and putting it all one line makes it quite unreadable.

Comment: Maybe it went wrong here: "'pivotedcol1'"

Comment: The query works in Oracle SQL Developer and I'm not able to define the `pivotedcol`s without ' ' in the `PIVOT` command, and as such I'm forced to use " " around them when I `SELECT` the columns. The query works though, so I'm not sure if that's the mistake. I just need an example of a multiline free form query in Sqoop with a similar scale of complexity, but can't find anything online.

Comment: Or $conditions?
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00911.php

Comment: And I presume you deleted all '\' characters?

Comment: $CONDITIONS is needed in the free-form query, [Your query must include the token $CONDITIONS which each Sqoop process will replace with a unique condition expression.](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html) and if I remove the '\' character, I get a `Malformed option in options file(file.props)` error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things here.

1. Put double quotes for SQL Query and remove backslashes (/)
2. Put backslash infront of $CONDITIONS.

   ```
   SELECT col1, col2 FROM table where rownum<=45000 AND \$CONDITIONS
   ```